# Error when creating a task in separate file in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

```
module tb();

    reg [7:0] a = 1;
    reg [7:0] b;

    initial begin
      AddTask(a, b);
      $display("%d", b);
    end

    task AddTask;

        input [7:0] a;
        output reg[7:0] b;

        begin
          b = a + 1;
        end

    endtask


endmodule
```

The above code is compiled and simulated correctly; But I want to cut the task "AddTask" from the module "tb.v" and place it in a separate module "AddModule.v"(that is in a separate file) for clear coding. When I do this, modelsim can compile it but can't simulate it and give the error:
`" Unresolved reference to 'AddTask' "`. Although I include AddModule.v, it can't recognize AddTask. Can you help me please, what's the wrong ?

```
module tb;

    reg [7:0] a = 1;
    reg [7:0] b;

    `include "AddModule.v"

    initial begin
      AddTask(a, b);
      $display("%d", b);
    end
 endmodule
```

### AddTask in a separate file:

```
module AddModule;

    task AddTask;

        input [7:0] a;
        output reg[7:0] b;

        begin
          b = a + 1;
        end

    endtask

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably the nested module declaration. This is not allowed in Verilog, however is possible in SystemVerilog.
Try to declare only the task `AddModule()` in a separate file without a surounding module declaration. This file can then be included within the scope of another module, e.g. within your testbench (as in your example code).

Comment: Thank's a lot @damage, I declared only AddTask in a separated file 'AddTask.v' without any module declaration and it worked !

Comment: Also,when I synthesized it in Quartus, at first it didn't synthesize, but when I changed the postfix of files from .v (Verilog) to .sv (System Verilog), it synthesized correctly in Quartus as well as simulated in Modelsim !